# How do I create constants to be used in Xamarin.Forms XML

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

As an Android developer I'm used to work with `@dimen/`-constants in Androids XML. I find this future useful because it allows me to easily change multiple places that should have the same pixel-length together.

Does Xamarin.Forms have a similar features that I can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well what you looking for are `ResourceDictionaries`

> XAML resources are definitions of objects that can be shared and re-used throughout a Xamarin.Forms application.
>   These resource objects are stored in a resource dictionary.

A `ResourceDictionary` is a repository for resources that are used by a Xamarin.Forms application. Typical resources that are stored in a ResourceDictionary include styles, control templates, data templates, colours, and converters.

In XAML, resources that are stored in a `ResourceDictionary` can then be retrieved and applied to elements by using the `StaticResource` markup extension. In `C#`, resources can also be defined in a `ResourceDictionary` and then retrieved and applied to elements by using a string-based indexer. However, there's little advantage to using a `ResourceDictionary` in `C#`, as shared objects can simply be stored as `fields` or `properties`, and accessed directly without having to first retrieve them from a `dictionary`.

**Creating and Consuming a ResourceDictionary**

`Resources` are defined in a `ResourceDictionary` that is then set to one of the following Resources properties:

- The Resources property of any class that derives from Application.
- The Resources property of any class that derives from VisualElement

A `Xamarin.Forms` program contains only one class that derives from `Application` but often makes use of many classes that derive from `VisualElement`, including pages, layouts, and controls. Any of these objects can have its Resources property set to a `ResourceDictionary`. Choosing where to put a particular `ResourceDictionary` impact where the resources can be used:

- Resources in a `ResourceDictionary` that is attached to a view such as `Button` or `Label` can only be applied to that particular object, so this is not very useful.
- `Resources` in a `ResourceDictionary` attached to a layout such as `StackLayout` or `Grid` can be applied to the layout and all the children of that layout.
- Resources in a `ResourceDictionary` defined at the page level can be applied to the page and to all its children.
- Resources in a `ResourceDictionary` defined at the application level can be applied throughout the application.

The following XAML shows resources defined in an application level `ResourceDictionary` in the `App.xaml` file created as part of the standard Xamarin.Forms program:

```
<Application ...>
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="PageBackgroundColor">Yellow</Color>
        <Color x:Key="HeadingTextColor">Black</Color>
        <Color x:Key="NormalTextColor">Blue</Color>
        <Style x:Key="LabelPageHeadingStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource HeadingTextColor}" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Beginning in `Xamarin.Forms` 3.0, the explicit `ResourceDictionary` tags are not required. The `ResourceDictionary` object is created automatically, and you can insert the resources directly between the Resources property-element tags:

```
<Application ...>
<Application.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="PageBackgroundColor">Yellow</Color>
    <Color x:Key="HeadingTextColor">Black</Color>
    <Color x:Key="NormalTextColor">Blue</Color>
    <Style x:Key="LabelPageHeadingStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource HeadingTextColor}" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Each resource has a key that is specified using the x:Key attribute, which becomes it dictionary key in the `ResourceDictionary`. The key is used to retrieve a resource from the `ResourceDictionary` by the `StaticResource` markup extension, as demonstrated in the following XAML code example that shows additional resources defined within the `StackLayout`:

```
<StackLayout Margin="0,20,0,0">
<StackLayout.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Style x:Key="LabelNormalStyle" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource NormalTextColor}" />
  </Style>
  <Style x:Key="MediumBoldText" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Medium" />
    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
  </Style>
 </ResourceDictionary>
 </StackLayout.Resources>
 <Label Text="ResourceDictionary Demo" Style="{StaticResource LabelPageHeadingStyle}" />
<Label Text="This app demonstrates consuming resources that have been defined in resource dictionaries."
       Margin="10,20,10,0"
       Style="{StaticResource LabelNormalStyle}" />
<Button Text="Navigate"
        Clicked="OnNavigateButtonClicked"
        TextColor="{StaticResource NormalTextColor}"
        Margin="0,20,0,0"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        Style="{StaticResource MediumBoldText}" />
</StackLayout>
```

For more detailed information kindly take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#creating-and-consuming-a-resourcedictionary)

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the StaticResource as mentioned above, 2 other ways to do it.

First one is, Having static class for constants and refer them in the XAML.

```
public static class GlobalSetting
{
    public static double ImageRotation { get { return 180; } }
}
```

In the Xaml, you need to add this namespace in the page directive,

```
xmlns:gb="clr-namespace:XXXX.StaticData"
```

and use the constant in the xaml code as below,

```
<Image Source="icon_back.png" Rotation="{x:Static gb:GlobalSetting.BackImageRotation}" HeightRequest="24" </Image>
```

Second approach is, having a constant parameter in the BaseViewModel, and binding them in the Xaml code.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you want to define constants/styles in a ResourceDictionary:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries.

In the ResourceDictionary you can define your constants/styles by key, in your XAML you can then refer to them as follows:

```
Color={StaticResource MyColorFromDictionary}
```